# Add and Remove a Shortcut on Applications Tab and Dock

Tags: 14.04, gnome, configuration, shortcuts, elementary

this would have connection with Ubuntu since i am using ElementaryOS Freya, given that i am new to Linux OS, i am wondering two things:

1. How can i make Application Shortcuts, just like on Windows ? i assume it is called as a "Application/Desktop Configuration File" or something .. one that has a Custom Name and a Custom Icon ? .. and how can i add it to my Applications Tab and Dock
2. Vice Versa of Q1 .. how can i remove an Application Shortcut on the Application Tab ? .. since on ElementaryOS there is no right click to remove it

i hope my question can be answered by anyone, sorry for my faulty english . not my language tho .. thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Questions that are about ElementaryOS and not about Ubuntu [are off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions). You should instead ask this somewhere ElementaryOS is supported, like [their answers site](http://elementaryos.org/support#), [their live support site](http://elementaryos.org/support/live), or [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [this application](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/alacarte/) It allows you to create, edit, or delete everything you see in the applications dialogues (Launchpad, applications menu).

Comment: will be testing it, i'll be right back. thanks :)

Comment: No Problem, glad I could help! :)